# Selecting Gnome from login screen launches Gnome Classic everytime

Tags: 11.10, gnome

I have installed gnome 3 with

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

on Ubuntu 11.10.

But when I choose the 'Gnome' profile on the login screen I get the 'Gnome Classic' profile instead. Nothing even similiar to the awesome screenshots I have seen on many blog posts.

How to launch the real 'Gnome'?

Thanks.

P.S Can this be because of not having the proper video drivers installed? Because I don't have yet...

Comment: Try running `Additional Drivers` from the dash, it should show if any proprietary drivers are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are talking about is the FALL BACK MOOD. it happens cause your device cannot support gnome shell. that might be because of VGA card (Geraphic card) 's poor performance.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you need the proper drivers to run GNOME 3.
If you have a newer Nvidia Card it's easy just search for nvidia-current in the software center or put `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`  into the terminal.

If you have an ATI card, IMHO DO NOT USE THE PROPRIETARY DRIVERS OPTION - it left my system unusable...

Install the newest drivers ATI Catalyst 11.9 in either x86 or x86_64 version whatever suits your needs...make sure to follow every step from this page "http://linux-software-news-tutorials.blogspot.com/2011/10/ubuntu-1110-oneiric-problems-with-ati.html"
in order to have it work properly.

> > > EDIT: The newest version seems to be ATI Catalyst 11.10...no idea how good it works all I can say is 11.9 works really good<<<

Comment: I have a nVidia Card and I have already the nvidia-current already installed. I continue to have the same problem, however.

Comment: what card do you have?

Comment: i have two: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 12)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GT215 [GeForce GT 335M] (rev a2)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't home for a while...in a terminal try running ' sudo nvidia-xconfig' and reboot your system. Just in case the driver wasn't active, this should activate it and configure xserver appropriately.